# How to stream YouTube video through MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: c#, xaml, youtube, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to stream youtube video through MediaPlayerElement.

```
MediaElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/embed/QTYVJhy04rs"));
```

I tried this code but it didn't work.

I want something similar to videos in [MSPowerUser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mspoweruser/9nblggh3lhg8) app.

[image]

Comment: You can try with [YoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor). However, please note that this may violate YouTube's terms of service: *You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate*.

Comment: @Scavenger If I use the download link to play YouTube video, View count won't increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using MyToolKit.Extended library for UWP apps with the 'YouTube' class in the 'MyToolKit.Multimedia' namespace.

```
string youtubeVideoID = "INSERT VIDEO ID"; // Set video id
YouTubeQuality youtubeQuality = YouTubeQuality.Quality720P; // Set video quality

YouTubeUri videoUri = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(youtubeVideoID, youtubeQuality);

// You can get Uri using videoUri.Uri and set the source to a media player
```

MyToolKit.Extended: https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit

Comment: please provide some link to the tool/library that you are refering ... maybe a citation from the documentation ... and be more specific than "contains a class with the ability" ... Maybe also a small code example as to how OP can use the said library

Comment: Sure. I will create another comment with the details.